# How can I get my full profile on linkedin API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve my profile from linkedin.

Basically doing this: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`

But it only shows the lite information. I found that I can add parameters to request more info, but seems it doesn't work...

For trying something simple, having the email:

It should be: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(email)`

But the response is literally that: `{}`

You can ask I have no permissions... but yes I have them...

Can show you the inspection token that I'm using:

[image]

So... what is the problem? My goal is to have ALL the information, like education, jobs, skills, etc... and I can't even get my email :(